# parsley.js select list value of zero - not working

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, parsley.js

I have a select list on my test form that I am trying to get to work with [parsley.js](http://parsleyjs.org/) validation.

The parsley validation does work, but only when the default value of the select list is a blank value, except I need to have a value of 0 (zero).

So when the value of zero is selected / displayed in the select list the select list should be red with indicating that there is an error.

**How do I get the select list to validate correctly, when I am using a default value of zero?**

Here is an example of my select list with the zero value:

```
<select name="availability_type" id="id_availability_type" data-parsley-id="1601" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-required-message="You must enter at least one Detail." class="input-xlarge2 standard_input_style parsley-success">
    <option value="0"> Do not display Availability</option>
    <option value="1">Immediately</option>
    <option value="2">1 week</option>
    <option value="3">2 weeks</option>
    <option value="4">3 weeks</option>
    <option value="5">4 weeks</option>
    <option value="6">&gt; 4 weeks</option>
</select>
```

Here is the code line that works with a blank space as the value:

```
<option value=" "> Do not display Availability</option>
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to use only the 'numbers' as option value?

Comment: yes. I have to use a number (0 - 6).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally got this to work using the **data-parsley-min="1"**.

This way the input will not accept the value of zero.

Hope that this helps some one.

Comment: You had to do this... <option value=""> Do not display Availability</option> instead of <option value=" "> Do not display Availability</option>

Answer (score 2):

To make it work properly you needed to do the following

```
<!--Do this-->
<select id="select-id" required="" data-parsley-required-message="You must select at least one option.">
  <option value=""> Do not display Availability</option>
  .
  .
</select>
```

Doing it witht **data-parsley-min="1".** would make your required message say something stupid like min value has to be at least 1 (even if you override it with the required message attribute)

Hope this helps any other person...

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="form-select" id="floatingSelect" aria-label="Floating label select example" data-parsley-required data-parsley-required-message="Please select Country">
<option value="">Choose..</option>
<option value="Ahmedabad">India</option>
<option value="Bombai">UAE</option>
<option value="Delhi">Thailand</option>
<option value="Jammu-Kashmir">Japan</option>
<option value="Jaipur">Irac</option>
<option value="Aagra">Canada</option>
</select>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).